# invoking shared library loader from c code

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I have a shared library that I would like to load twice in my program. 
The use case is as following:

- Open program (and load library)
- Call Function F1() from library
- detach library from program
- load library again and re-initialize all variables
- Call Function F1() from library again

Is there a way from C/C++ code to do this?
I am interested in a solution that works with gcc/g++

Comment: This is an unusual requirement. Are you working around some sort of a problem?

Comment: Yes. I don't have access to the library code and it seems that (many) static variables need to be re-initialized before using the function F1 again.

Comment: Use libtool's [libltdl](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libtool.html#Using-libltdl). It's a comprehensive solution that covers essentially all major platforms.

Answer (score 4):

At first I was thinking about [LoadLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx), [GetProcAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx) and [FreeLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683152(v=vs.85).aspx) but then I mentioned that you want `gcc/g++`, which *looks like* you need *NIX solution. So I just have stolen solution from [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-porting/):

**loadlib.h**

```
#ifndef  __LOADLIB_H
#define  __LOADLIB_H

#ifdef UNIX
#include <dlfcn.h>
#endif 

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef void* (*funcPtr)();

#ifdef UNIX
#  define IMPORT_DIRECTIVE __attribute__((__visibility__("default")))
#  define CALL  
#else
#  define IMPORT_DIRECTIVE __declspec(dllimport) 
#  define CALL __stdcall
#endif

extern "C" {
  IMPORT_DIRECTIVE void* CALL LoadLibraryA(const char* sLibName); 
  IMPORT_DIRECTIVE funcPtr CALL GetProcAddress(
                                    void* hModule, const char* lpProcName);
  IMPORT_DIRECTIVE bool CALL  FreeLibrary(void* hLib);
}

#endif
```

**Loadlib.cpp**

```
#include "loadlib.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
  {
  #ifndef UNIX
    char* fileName = "hello.dll";
    void* libraryHandle = LoadLibraryA(fileName);
    if (libraryHandle == NULL)
      cout << "dll not found" << endl;
    else  // make a call to "printHello" from the hello.dll 
      (GetProcAddress(libraryHandle, "printHello"))();
    FreeLibrary(libraryHandle);
#else // unix
    void (*voidfnc)(); 
    char* fileName = "hello.so";
    void* libraryHandle = dlopen(fileName, RTLD_LAZY);
    if (libraryHandle == NULL)
      cout << "shared object not found" << endl;
    else  // make a call to "printHello" from the hello.so
      {
      voidfnc = (void (*)())dlsym(libraryHandle, "printHello"); 
      (*voidfnc)();
      }
    dlclose(libraryHandle);
  #endif

  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like what I need.

Comment: You might want to test the return value of  `dlsym` for `NULL` before calling the function

Comment: @tofro sure, as well as `GetProcAddress`. See, even IBM's code is crazy buggy sometimes ))))